# UIImageView background/transparency

Tags: objective-c, xcode, background, transparency

I want two (or more) UIImageViews to have pictures in it and be conected without white space between them. Simply if first image is straight line and second one too, I want them to look like onw long line no like two separated lines. How is it possible to do so? When I overlay both UIImageViews or put them near to each other in my storyboard there is still gap between those lines in simulator view. I am one hundred percent sure that both pictures have no frame around them when I open them in Preview or Gimp or any other app. Line just stars at 0px and ends at the absolut end of picture. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set the imageView's properties:

```
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
imgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

In thins case imageviews will definetely be without any whitespaces between them, although the aspect ratio may be changed
If UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill doesn't met your requirements try `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`

Comment: Yes that't it but when I use `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` it makes no difference and `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` crops from picture about 2 milimeters. What's wrong?

Comment: Read carefully about these keys and I think you will understand the difference http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html